# Using jQuery form validator inside onBegin method of Ajax.BeginForm in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

jQuery form validator works fine with Html.Beginform.

I changed Html.Beginform to Ajax.Beginform for submitting form without refresh (tried Ajax post but file is coming as null in controller) .

After changing to Ajax.Beginform jQuery form validator is not working.

Is it possible to use jQuery form validator inside onBegin method of Ajax.Beginform?

**View:**

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "Success", OnFailure = "Failure", OnBegin = "validate", HttpMethod = "post" }, new { @Id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<script>
    function Success(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
    function Failure() {
        alert("failure");
    }
    function validate() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    text1: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    text2: {
                        required: true,

                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    text1: {
                        required: "enter text1"
                    },
                    text2: {
                        required: "enter text2"
                    },
                }

            });
            if ($("#form").valid()) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
</script>

<div>
    <input type="text" id="text" name="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
</div>

}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formcollection)
        {
            return Json("1");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes it's possible but you have to show us some codes

Comment: Now check @GGO ...if i use jquery validator within onBegin function its throwing below error.

Comment: 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'

Comment: @GGO please help

Comment: Sorry it was weekend here

Answer (score 1):

Firstable you include unobstrusive jquery validator yet. You could use `data-val` html attributes on inputs to auto validate fields, and your code would be more readable. Try to see documentation about unobstrusive validation.

Your problem is the `Ajax.BeginForm` call. See visual studio auto-complete to check method parameters. It missing a parameter, you have to put a `null` value for `routeValues` parameter, like that :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "Success", OnFailure = "Failure", OnBegin = "validate", HttpMethod = "post" }, new { @Id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: Hi @ggo ...now I can able to validate and also able to submit...now again new problem is if I add file  input it's coming as null in form collection,model and also in httppostedfilebase....

Comment: If my answer solve the inital problem, check and close this topic with the green tick please. If you have another problem, like your file input, you have to make another topic with the concerned code. Thanks